# Covering of discrete probability measures

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, pr.probability, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{P}_{n:+}(\mathbb{R})$ denote the set of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ for the form $\sum_{i=1}^n k_i \delta_{x_i}$ where $k_i>0$.  Then any measure in $\mathcal{P}_{n:+}(\mathbb{R})$ is in the image of the map on $\Delta_n \times \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\Delta_n$ is interior of the $n$-simplex (i.e.: $k_1,\dots,k_n \in (0,1)$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n k_i =1$, taking $(k_1,\dots,k_n)\times (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ to $\sum_{i=1}^n k_j \delta_{x_i}$.  Clearly this map is continuous, when $\mathcal{P}_{n:+}(\mathbb{R})$ is equipped with the Prokhorov metric.

However, is it a *[covering map](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoveringMap.html)*?  I have not been able to disprove it so I'm thinking maybe it is...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This map is not a covering one, because the preimages of singleton sets under this map are not of the same cardinality. E.g., the cardinality of the preimage of the singleton set $\{\frac1n\,\sum_{j=1}^n\delta_j\}$ is $n!$, whereas the preimage of the singleton set $\{\delta_0\}$ is of infinite cardinality.

---

From the site you linked to: "[for a covering map $f\colon X\to Y$,] the cardinal number of $f^{-1}(y)$ (which is possibly infinite) is independent of the choice of $y$ in $Y$."

Comment: So if we replace $\mathcal{P}_{n:+}$ with the set $\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n k_i\delta_{x_i}:k_i>0,\, x_i\neq x_j \mbox{ if } i\neq j\right\}$ then this should work?

Comment: @James_T : I think so.